# std::logic_error classes are different kinds of std::invalid_argument, aren't they?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, std

Let's have a look at classes that are derived from `std::logic_error`:

- `std::out_of_range` is thrown when argument is out of range.
- `std::length_error` is thrown when argument that specifies a length is out of supported values.
- `std::domain_error` is supposed to be thrown when an argument is outside of expected domain.
- `std::future_error` is thrown when `std::future` without a shared state is used (if we take the object as a hidden argument of a method, then `std::future` is an argument too).

It seems that all of the exceptions above are thrown when an invalid argument is passed (invalid position, invalid length, invalid future). If so, why are they not derived from `std::invalid_argument`? Should I derive my errors from `std::invalid_argument`
or from `std::logic_error`?

Are there a logic errors that are not related to an invalid argument usage?

Answer (score 3):

Those first three exceptions *may* indicate that an argument is, for example, out of range.

They may also indicate that something else is out of range.

That could be the result of a calculation, or data provided from a service.

Not every piece of information is an argument.

---

As for `future_error`…

> if we take the object as a hidden argument of a method, then `std::future` is an argument too

That interpretation is based on implementation details, which should not come into play when designing a class heirarchy or when describing semantically what a thing does. Logically, the `std::future` throws the exception, not some would-be free function that takes a `std::future` as an argument. As a result, again, the thing that's "wrong" is not an argument.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's implementation details. The arguments of a method are input. The object for which a method is called is input as well. The difference is only in syntaxis. I don't think we need different names for similar concepts.

Comment: @anton_rh You may think that, but that doesn't change the actual facts. The object on which a member function is invoked is not generally considered to be an "argument", even though the call is usually _implemented_ by passing a pointer in a hidden first argument. The names of types in the C++ standard library, or the inheritance hierarchy thereof, are not determined by implementation details (see also: `std::map` is not `std::tree`).